# Symfony 1.4 empty decoratorDirectory setting not being populated

Tags: php, macos, apache, symfony-1.4

I'm working on a legacy symfony 1.4 project, I setup my local dev environment at my office linux machine Fedora 16 and everything went well. I had to recreate the environment for a macbook machine with Mac OS X Lion.

In the second I get a ton of errors like this

```
[Mon Mar 04 16:51:58 2013] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'sfRenderException' with message 'The decorator template "layout.php" does not exist or is unreadable in "".' in /Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/cache/something/something/config/config_core_compile.yml.php:3875\nStack trace:\n#0 /Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/cache/something/something/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(3909)
```

So in that `config_core_compile.yml.php` file the exception is being thrown in this code

```
if (!is_readable($this->getDecoratorDirectory().'/'.$this->getDecoratorTemplate()))
{
throw new sfRenderException(sprintf('The decorator template "%s" does not exist or is unreadable in "%s".', $this->decoratorTemplate, $this->decoratorDirectory));
}
```

Tracking the getDecoratorDirectory method call I got to sfView.class.php around line 175

```
public function getDecoratorDirectory()
{
return $this->decoratorDirectory;
}
```

In that same file is where the decoratorDirectory property gets 'calculated/populated'But is being blank, do you any clue of what might be wrong? a symfony setting, an apache config? Anything?

P.S just in case this is my apache vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName local.myapp
DocumentRoot /Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/web


ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/local.myapp-error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/local.myapp-access_log" combined

<Directory "/Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/web">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>


Alias /sf /Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/web/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
<Directory "/Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/web/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT:
Also I have to use perforce the company repos, an older teammate keeps saying he thinks is about encoding, it doesn't make sense to me, but still.

Comment: Hey there Elnur and j0k, how are you? What was the editing you did?

Comment: Are you using same apache, same php? Does the file `layout.php` exists inside the templates folder of you app? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: In the linux box I have apache 2.2 if I recall correctly, php was 5.4.*

In the mac box, I have php 5.3.15 and Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 with Suhosin-Patch

yes I've clear the cache folder quite a few times. I have multiple symfony apps within the project, all but one have the layout.php file inside their templates folder, looking into it...

Comment: j0k, so it is normal/usual for the decoratorDirectory property to be blank?

Comment: Yeah is very weird, any clue?

Comment: There is an error in your definition of `alias` in `vhost`. The path should be `../myApp/v2/lib/vendor...` so without the `web` part. Though I don't think it's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Still need to try, so it will end up as:

Alias /sf /Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/web/lib/vendor
<Directory "/Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/web/lib/vendor">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>

?

Comment: I pretty much followed http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration for the apache vhost

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but some times when I have moved one symfony application to a different server or to a different folder I have had to remove all the cache folder, because symfony use absolute paths sometimes.

Well, try to remove all content on the cache folder. Probably you will need to fix permissions on this folder, because symfony needs to create directories on this folder. (Probably).

Sorry, I dont speak english enought to explain well.

Comment: No worries, english is not my first lang either, yup you explained yourself great.

Yeah I've clear cache completely, the cache folder has 777 permissions. Don't know what else I should check, the vhost looked ok?

Comment: I think that vhost is not the problem. But, there are something strange...In the stack trace: ".../Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/cache/something/something/config/config_core_compile.yml.php(3909)" this path is not the same of your application: /Users/foo/bar/baz/myApp/v2/  (v2 is not in stack trace advertisement...)

Comment: Yeah symfony is caching stuff, and the file that throws the exception is a cached file. Also I might forgot to add the v2 part, I put a fictitious path to not show my real path.